# How to render wbmp image within html?

Tags: html, image, rendering

I wrote following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="thieftitle.wbmp" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">

</body>
</html>
```

> thieftitle.wbmp

locates near the my html.

html renders like this.
[image]

As you can see resource loads successfully but not render.

I there way to fix it?

Comment: Have you confirmed that any browser supports such a format? A quick Google search suggests it's not supported in Chrome, and a feature request to implement in Firefox was closed as "wontfix". There are also several suggestions that any effort to support the format has been removed from Gecko altogether. You may simply have to use a more widely supported format for your images

Comment: I tryed opera IE chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve no idea why one would use WBMP nowadays but you might have your reasons—so here we go. As @Clive already pointed out, browsers don’t support this format, so this leaves us with two options:

1. Convert the image on the server-side and send a GIF or PNG to the client
2. Decode the image in JavaScript and and write the pixels onto a `canvas` element

I’ll focus on option 2.

## Implementation

Get this library: https://github.com/andreasgal/wbmp.js

(or write your own decoder, it’s no rocket sience)

```
<body>
    <div id="image-container"></div>
    <script src="wbmp.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            WBMP.decode(img, 'test.wbmp');
            document.getElementById('image-container').appendChild(img);
        }());
    </script>
</body>
```

## Result

[image: WBMP reader]

## Caveats

### Browser support

This only works in browser that support the `canvas` element and are able to retrieve binary data. Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays and http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas for details. Spoiler: This works in IE 10 and up. If you need to support older IE versions, pick option 1.

### Bandwidth usage

WBMP is uncompressed and wastes bandwidth. Depending on what you’re trying to achieve, it might be cheaper to pick option 1.

Comment: I’ve edited my post because I noticed that my first implementation causes the browser to parse the WBMP and fail before it’s handled by the JavaScript library. That’s why I decided to create the `img` programmatically.